# Bundle from Compiler pass?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Is there any way (other than tag parameters) to access the "providing" bundle (object or name) during a compiler pass that is collecting tagged services?

```
class MyContainerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('my.service')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('my.service');

        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('my.tag') as $id => $linkContainer) {
             // here is where I would like the bundle name or object
             $definition->addMethodCall('add', array(new Reference($id)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the bundle name? Just asking because you might be able to achive what you want in another way.

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm building an array of tagged services and want to include the bundle name as part of the index of the array.

like `$definition->addMethodCall('add', [$bundleName . ':' . $id, new Reference($id)]);`

Comment: Ok, but why do you want to store the bundle name? is it needed inside your logic?

Comment: yes, I use it later in the logic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to get the bundle name dynamically.